# Where to find documentations about Django ORM's return types/possible exceptions raised

Tags: python, django, orm, error-handling

Is there any documentation about how django handles different ORM problems/errors for methods:

- MyModel.objects.get(name='myname')
- myModel.save()
- myModel.delete()

I have read the documentation on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/ and find that some problems seem to raise exception, is this the case for all get, save, delete methods or are some of them just returning None or False. I cannot find any documentation that clearly states what kind of returns or exceptions to expect.

What is the coding conventions for this if I for example want to check if a username is free and don't want my code to die if user does not exist?

```
user = User.objects.get(username='myusername')
if not user:
    return True

return False
```

or

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username='myusername')
except:
    return True

return False
```

or

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username='myusername')
except:
    user = None

if not user:
    return True

return False
```

And what values can save and delete return or do they always raise exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at django.core.exceptions.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/exceptions/#module-django.core.exceptions

Comment: Thanks that helps! Does this mean that the ORM's methods for getting, saving and deleting always raises exceptions if something bad happens rather than returns False of None? (I'm fairly new to Django and python)

Comment: Yes. In your case django provides a shortcut, get_or_create might be what your looking for  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create